# Android: Fixed-width numbers being shown (incorrectly) in API 29 and up

Tags: android, fonts, tabular

I've tried so many ways to dive into this issue but can't find a fix. Has anyone had something similar?

On phones with API 29 and up, Android is showing our font with tabular (i.e. fixed-width/monospaced) numbers as a default. On API 28 and lower, the (correct/desired) proportional numbers are displayed.

To see what I mean, look at the 1's in the following two images:

What we want (and what we see on API <= 28):
[image: What we want (and what we see on API <= 28)]

What we're seeing on API >= 29:
[image: What we're seeing on API >= 29]

I've tried every version I can of setting both/either fontFeatureSettings and/or fontVariationSettings--using all combinations of tnum (or tnum 0) and pnum (or pnum 1)--to no avail.

Any thoughts? This has driven me crazy all day.

Comment: "Tabular" is the font name right?

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry for the confusion. I mean "Tabular" as in the style specified by css etc., i.e. https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/proportional-vs-tabular-figures. (In other words, monospace).

Comment: And what font are you using? If the font is built-in, it may have changed in API 29.

Comment: @Nicolas We're supplying our own. Same font file supplied in all cases.